# Spring Security 3 with Extjs - Login Page - not redirect to home

Tags: spring, extjs, authentication, spring-security, extjs4.1

i am trying to make login with extjs form using this form:

```
{
            xtype : 'form',
            name: 'authenticationBox',
            width: 250,
            bodyPadding:5,
            fieldDefaults: {
                msgTarget: 'side',
                labelWidth: 75
            },
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            url:'j_spring_security_check',
            items:[{
                fieldLabel: 'Login',
                name: 'j_username',
                allowBlank:false
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                inputType: 'password',
                name: 'j_password',
                allowBlank:false
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Reset',
                action: 'reset'
            },{
                text: 'Submit',
                action:'auth'
            }]
    }
```

and the button handler is:

```
 onSubmitLogin : function(button){
    var me = this,
        form = button.up().up().getForm();// get the basic form
    if (form.isValid()) { // make sure the form contains valid data before submitting
        form.submit({
            success: function(form, action) {
               Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
            },
            failure: function(form, action) {
             console.log(action.result);
             //var msg = action.result.msg;
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', 'failed');
            }
        });
    } else { // display error alert if the data is invalid
        Ext.Msg.alert('Invalid Data', 'Please correct form errors.');
    }
}
```

My security context xml is :

```
    <http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true"
    use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/public" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="authenticated" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http> 

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="vitorn" password="password1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I have this controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/"+HOME_PAGE_NAME)
public ModelAndView showHomePage() {
    logger.info("trying to show home!");
    String username = getUsername();
    if(!username.equals(ANONYMOUS_USER)){
        logger.info("authenticated - show home!");
        return new ModelAndView(HOME_PAGE_NAME);
    }

    //ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(LOGIN_PAGE_NAME);
    return new ModelAndView(LOGIN_PAGE_NAME);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView openLoginPage() {
    logger.info("trying to show login!");

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(LOGIN_PAGE_NAME);
    return model;
}
```

When i make login on google chrome, i see my post in network  with values j_username:vitorn
j_password:password1 but without any response and after i see redirect to home page with this error: Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:

I had read many tutorials without successful. Can i can change do redirect automatically to home page after successful login ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a help here:
integrating spring security3 with extjs
http://javajeedevelopment.blogspot.fr/2011/02/integrating-spring-security-3-with.html